# JavaMailSender sends email to the wrong port on Heroku, but on localhost to the right one

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I'm using `JavaMailSender` and Outlook SMTP server for sending emails in a SpringBoot project.

**Mail config**:

```
host=smtp-mail.outlook.com
port=587
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.debug=true
```

When testing locally, everything works fine - email is sent to port `587` (see below) and delivered to the user.

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port 587, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port: 587
```

**The problem**: When testing on production (Heroku server), email is being sent to port `5104`:

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port 5104, isSSL false
```

That eventually ends with timed out connection exception and email is never sent to the user.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out). Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp-mail.outlook.com, 5104; timeout -1;
```

Edit: I've also figured that it uses different port on every email send try:

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp-mail.outlook.com", port 58079, isSSL false
```

**What is the reason for this behaviour? Why is it not using given port?**

Comment: How did you fix it?